# How to use substr on rs.status() of mongodb to get hostname only

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, substr, replicaset

I'd like to retrieve all host names without port number using rs.status() in MongoDB replica set.
I tried below one but it is not giving the required output.

```
MongoDB Enterprise rsMDB001P:PRIMARY> print([{ $substr: ["$rs.status().members[0].name", 0, 13]}])

[object Object]
```

Can someone correct my syntax to get required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
rs.status().members.forEach(function (m) { print(m.name.split(":").shift()) })
```

If you like to skip also the host domain, then use

```
rs.status().members.forEach(function (m) { print(m.name.split(":").shift().split(".").shift()) })
```